# How do I alter the transition of my slide in full-width menu

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a basic, fullscreen, slide in menu. It expands outwards from the top left-hand corner to fit the full screen. However, I dont want it to expand outwards. Instead, I want it to slide in from the left only to take up the full screen. Is this possible?

```
<div class="top">
    <!-- place brand icon here -->
</div>

<div class="menu-collapsed">
  <div class="bar"></div>
       <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  
</div>


<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis sunt mollitia molestiae maxime, voluptatibus, voluptas placeat minima natus temporibus culpa repudiandae! Nam porro molestiae possimus, laboriosam, vero tenetur consequatur voluptatibus?</p>



html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #369;
}

body.no-scroll {
    overflow-y:hidden;  
}

.top {
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:#202020;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

.menu-collapsed {
  transition: all .25s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-collapsed ul {
  transition: all .05s;
  position: fixed;
  left: -9000px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:none;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 36px;
  top: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.bar:before {
  transition: all .25s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -12px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.bar:after {
  transition: all .25s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.menu-expanded {
  transition: all 8.25s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.menu-expanded ul {
  transition: all .05s;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 8888;
  display:block;
}
.menu-expanded a {
  transition: all .15s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
}
.menu-expanded a:hover {
  transition: all .15s;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
.menu-expanded .bar {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .25s;
  right:50px;
}
.menu-expanded .bar:before {
  transition: all .25s;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -0px;
}
.menu-expanded .bar:after {
  transition: all .25s;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
}

p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}




$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu-collapsed').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('menu-expanded');
      $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
    });
});
```

I have placed it on codepen (For some reason it doesn't work at all on here) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ywypby but I recon this is because Codepen wont run the script.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your animation doesn't work in codepen is you don't have JQuery loaded in the JS section. Just click the little settings icon and have it loaded in the project.

To get you animation to slide in from left, you just need to target your transition on .menu-collapsed and .menu-expanded....

Instead of

```
transition: all XXs;
```

do

```
transition: width XXs;
```

The XXs is just the time for your transition.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ywypby

Comment: Thank you very much @jared. I figured the link to JQuery was needed but wasn't sure how I add this in Codepen. Thanks to you I now know. Plus changing all to width works perfect. I did try 'left' but that did jack sh*t :)